# Electron builder to overwrite existing gihub release files

Tags: github, electron, electron-builder

I'm using travis to deploy my electron applications as a draft release. I want the electron builder to upload the artifacts after each successful build in to github. So the latest stable release is available on github.

However when electron builder is trying to upload the file, if it already exists in github it does not overwrite it. Is there an option to do this via electron builder?

If not what kind of cli task/tool that i can use to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @IsmailMoghul no I did not. Ended up writing a script do it.

Answer (score 0):

Electron builder should automatically overwrite any existing GitHub release files with the same name.

However, as shown in the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3559), there seems to be a reoccurring bug that affected this back in 2018/2019 and more recently in late 2021. As such, downgrading to an older version of electron builder fixed the issue for me.

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3559

Comment: But what about the security patches? Downgrading is not an option.

Comment: As per the Github Issue - this is now fixed again 15 days ago - and will be included in v23.0.0-alpha.1 release - So should be released fully soonish...